# How to change the width and height of the react-select automatically React-js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have select element and I want to change the width and height of the element using `value.lenght` my code look like this :

```
width: `${(8*newValue.length) + 100}px`,
height: ,
```

when `width` is more then `300px` then `height+50px`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on use cases. You can control it using bootstrap grid system like `row` and `col`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this.

```
style={(8*newValue.length) + 100>300?{width: `${(8*newValue.length) + 100}px`,height:`${height + 50}px`}:{width: `${(8*newValue.length) + 100}px`,height:`${height}px`}}
```